# Retrieve server resource usage data by user from a Windows Server (same information in Task Manager>Users)

Tags: windows-server

We run a Server running Windows Server 2022 Datacenter. We are looking for a programmatic way to extract data on server resources used by each user.

Specifically, we need the following information:

- User ID
- Status (active/disconnected)
- RAM utilization
- RAM usage percentage
- CPU usage percentage

[This is the kind of information available on Windows Task Manager > More Details > Users]

With this information, we will create a dashboard, making resource use transparent to other users. That is, we want to create a table containing something equivalent to TaskManager>Users (as in image below), but adding a column with the user name names (corresponding to the user ID). We want to update this information every 30s.

[image]

are there any sheel commands to extract this information? Or any other alternative?

[obs: this question was [originally posted on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1146930/retrieve-server-usage-data-by-user-from-a-windows-server-same-information-in-ta), but considered of topic there]